# How to make siri "Show alert" without speaking out the text from it's variable, in Apple Shortcuts

Tags: macos, mac, audio, siri, shortcuts-app

I am trying to make a coding assistant in Siri. I make an API request to ChatGPT, and then have "Show alert" show value to display the text of the variable "Dictionary Value", and then if I press "okay" it copies it to clipboard. This speeds up coding queries.

The problem is, when it shows the alert it speaks out the text which is annoying.
I only want to read it, and decide if it's good code.

Does anyone know a way to make it Show Alert without siri speaking out the result?
I tried Show Result but it spoke it too.
I tried Overlay Text but couldn't get this to work either.
Thanks for reading, I hope you can help me.